# Graphing code using PySimpleGUI, MatPlotLib and tkinter crashing on selecting function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm, pysimplegui

Hello lovely clever people. I came across this beautiful piece of code that in theory should help me with a project I'm working on. However, each time I run it and select an option from the list, it crashes. The original piece of code was over 900 lines, and can be found here:
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/e59b0060b6837cfb9ec3809da51e4fe04358b6ee/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib_Browser_Paned.py

I have reduced it to bare bones to see if I could get it working, but with no luck.

The goal is to get a functioning graphing options list to appear beside a canvas containing the corresponding graph and be able to update the graph based on the choice made by the user.

Thank you in advance!

I am using:
Pycharm 2.5 Community Edition
MatPlotLib version 3.1.1
PySimpleGui version 4.1
Numpy version 1.17

On Mac Os Mojave 10.14.6

I have updated everything that I could. I've also tried running it on a Windows machine, resulting in the same error message.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasAgg
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
import inspect
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as Tk


def PyplotHistogram():
    np.random.seed(0)

    n_bins = 10
    x = np.random.randn(1000, 3)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
    ax0, ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes.flatten()

    colors = ['red', 'tan', 'lime']
    ax0.hist(x, n_bins, density=1, histtype='bar', color=colors, label=colors)
    ax0.legend(prop={'size': 10})
    ax0.set_title('bars with legend')

    ax1.hist(x, n_bins, density=1, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
    ax1.set_title('stacked bar')

    ax2.hist(x, n_bins, histtype='step', stacked=True, fill=False)
    ax2.set_title('stack step (unfilled)')

    # Make a multiple-histogram of data-sets with different length.
    x_multi = [np.random.randn(n) for n in [10000, 5000, 2000]]
    ax3.hist(x_multi, n_bins, histtype='bar')
    ax3.set_title('different sample sizes')

    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig


def draw_figure(canvas, figure, loc=(0, 0)):
    """ Draw a matplotlib figure onto a Tk canvas
    loc: location of top-left corner of figure on canvas in pixels.
    Inspired by matplotlib source: lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py
    """
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = figure.bbox.bounds
    figure_w, figure_h = int(figure_w), int(figure_h)
    photo = Tk.PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=figure_w, height=figure_h)

    # Position: convert from top-left anchor to center anchor
    canvas.create_image(loc[0] + figure_w/2, loc[1] + figure_h/2, image=photo)

    # Unfortunately, there's no accessor for the pointer to the native renderer
    tkagg.blit(photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)

    # Return a handle which contains a reference to the photo object
    # which must be kept live or else the picture disappears
    return photo


fig_dict = {'Pyplot Histogram' : PyplotHistogram}


sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('LightGreen')
figure_w, figure_h = 650, 650
# define the form layout
listbox_values = [key for key in fig_dict.keys()]
col_listbox = [[sg.Listbox(values=listbox_values, change_submits=True, size=(28, len(listbox_values)), key='func')],
               [sg.T(' ' * 12), sg.Exit(size=(5, 2))]]

col_multiline = sg.Column([[sg.Multiline(size=(70, 35), key='multiline')]])
col_canvas = sg.Column([[ sg.Canvas(size=(figure_w, figure_h), key='canvas')]])

layout = [[sg.Text('Matplotlib Plot Test', font=('current 18'))],
          [sg.Column(col_listbox), sg.Pane([col_canvas, col_multiline], size=(800,600))],
          ]

# create the form and show it without the plot
window = sg.Window('Demo Application - Embedding Matplotlib In PySimpleGUI',resizable=True, grab_anywhere=False).Layout(layout)
window.Finalize()

canvas_elem = window.FindElement('canvas')
multiline_elem= window.FindElement('multiline')

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    # print(event)
    # show it all again and get buttons
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break

    try:
        choice = values['func'][0]
        func = fig_dict[choice]
    except:
        pass

    multiline_elem.Update(inspect.getsource(func))
    plt.clf()
    fig = func()
    fig_photo = draw_figure(canvas_elem.TKCanvas, fig)


*** ERROR MESSAGE ***

/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/venv/bin/python "/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/breakdown graph options.py"
/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/breakdown graph options.py:5: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The matplotlib.backends.tkagg module was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.0 and will be removed in 3.2.
  import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
*** Changing look and feel is not supported on Mac platform ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 27, in blit
    dataptr, colormode, bboxptr)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "PyAggImagePhoto"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/breakdown graph options.py", line 103, in <module>
    fig_photo = draw_figure(canvas_elem.TKCanvas, fig)
  File "/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/breakdown graph options.py", line 56, in draw_figure
    tkagg.blit(photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/Users/thewarpdrive/PycharmProjects/sports/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 28, in blit
    except tk.TclError:
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'TclError'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue opened on the PySimpleGUI GitHub about problems using Matplotlib 3.1.1 with PySimpleGUI.
Reported and discussed in these issues.

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1620
https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1713

Try installing Matplotlib 3.0.3 instead.

You may find that you can get quicker answers by searching the project's GitHub.

Comment: You are an angel MikeyB!!! Thank you! Rolling back to 3.0.3 worked a treat! I had posted about this on GitHub a couple of days ago, but I've found people here so helpful and knowledgeable that I thought I'd try here too, and I'm very glad I did!

Comment: Can you please tell me the issue number?  The GitHub is the better of the 2 locations for this particular project.

Comment: Sure thing it is #1775